# Tabelas com Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Comecei ontem com Bootstrap e ainda estou na curva do aprendizado. A minha necessidade é uma tabela com duas colunas, uma forma de um grid. Nessa tabela tenho apenas duas colunas: CNPJ e Razão Social. E faço uma consulta no BD e trago CNPJ e Razão e vou preenchendo essas colunas respectivamente. Há algum exemplo de algo parecido? Estou mergulhando de cabeça no Bootstrap.

Comment: Encontrei o exemplo.

Comment: Você quer usando AJAX ou Post?

Comment: uso ajax com jquery para popular. A questão agora é trabalhar com o tamanho. Tudo no bootstrap por default é 100% e preciso criar uma tabela estreita, pois o restantante ao lado da tabela, será usado para outras informações.

Comment: Leia primeiro a parte de containers: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Ela te ensina como dividir a tela do jeito que você precisa.

Comment: Se você colocar um exemplo da sua View, coloco uma resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Para criar o layout proposto, eis o exemplo abaixo :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">CNPJ</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Razão Social</div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">123456789</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Teste</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">123456789</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Teste</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Veja o exemplo em http://www.bootply.com/fnNWhNA2Fe

Mas para seu caso, creio que seja melhor trabalhar com uma tabela dentro de uma grid. Assim você pode ter a tabela com as duas colunas, e deixar o espaço para outras informações, conforme você comentou :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>CNPJ</th>
                    <th>Razão Social</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123456789</td>
                    <td>Teste</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123456789</td>
                    <td>Teste</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123456789</td>
                    <td>Teste</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123456789</td>
                    <td>Teste</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>123456789</td>
                    <td>Teste</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Outras informações</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Veja a demonstração em http://www.bootply.com/WaMMYR6N16

Comment: Só é preciso tomar cuidado com qual versão do Bootstrap se está usando. Classes como `col-md-x` por exemplo estão presentes apenas na versão mais recente do Bootstrap, a partir da `3.x.x`. Apenas um comentário adicional =)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap é uma estrutura de HTML5 e CSS3 projetado para ajudá-lo com o front-end no desenvolvimento de aplicações web e sites, contudo suas funcionalidades são mais voltadas para a parte visual e sua programação é mais voltada para o gerenciamento de controle. Você pode usar o Bootstrap basicamente para o layout, os elementos principais que ele boostrap trabalha são: Glyphicons, Dropdowns, Button groups, Button dropdowns, Input groups, Navs, Navbar, Breadcrumbs, Pagination, Labels, Badges, Jumbotron, Page header, Thumbnails, Alerts, Progress bars, Media object, Panels, Responsive embed, Wells, Back to top e Preview theme você pode encontrar informações sobre o uso de cada uma delas no [site oficial](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), existem recursos como modal e outros que também são suportados mas todos são basicamente voltado para layout, se você busca apenas a formatação dos dados e você quer usar o boostrap para o layout da sua página ele é uma boa solução, se você acessar a parte de [css no site do boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) vai encontrar exemplos de como formatar sua tabela para ela usar as classes do boostrap e assim ficar com o layout conforme especificado. Só de aplicar a classe "table" já vai estar usando parte do padrão do boostrap.

```
<table class="table">
  ...
</table>
```

Se desejar fazer controle de paginação ao trazer os dados para formatar em uma grid permitir pesquisa e etc... Vai precisar de outro recurso eu aconselho o em [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) que pode ser usado com o layout do boostrap. Fácil de usar, simples, bem documentado e funcional. Você pode [aplicar o estilo do bootstrap no DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).